# Handle UIAlertController in XCTest

Tags: ios, swift, xctest

I'm trying to test `In-App Purchase` with sandbox account in `XCUITest`. I know how to handle async system alert with `addUIInterruptionMonitor` and it worked with system alerts like push notification permission or location service permission.

When I tried with `In-App Purchase` sign-in pop up, the closure of `addUIInterruptionMonitor` is not invoked. Is this kind of `UIAlertController` not able to handle with `XCUITest`?